# Even though it looks easy, oddly enough it's not (treated in two different ways)

Tags: knowledge, visual

**What's the answer to this "simple" puzzle?**

---

[image]

8

22

17

104

2

19

200

---

Hint 1

> *Even* though it looks easy, *odd*ly enough it's not (treated in two different ways)

Comment: It doesn't look easy at all :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the

> [Collatz Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture)
>  The title describes this, *even* and *odd* are different, and the jumpy stair pattern as the numbers (allegedly) always trend to 1 are shown in the image

> The numbers spell out C O L L A T Z when the number of steps to reach 1 is converted to letters A=1, B=2 etc
>  see: https://www.omnicalculator.com/math/collatz-conjecture
>  (note, all numbers from this site must be reduced by 1 as it counts the staring number as step 1 but the puzzle does not)